# Infor reporting issue

Tags: sql-server, windows, reporting-services

I'm using Windows Server 2012. I want to connect infor reporting application with SQL Server 2014 which is on the same machine, but when I try I get an error

> Unable to communicate with the database host machine. Check host machine and the SQL server Authentication username and password

I'm using SQL Server authentication, and my username and password are correct. My firewalls are turned off. There is no antivirus.

What is blocking me?

Comment: Can you post the documentation you are following. I see [here](http://docplayer.net/18238199-Infor-m3-report-manager-solution-consultant.html) that 2012 & 2008 are supported (assuming 2014 & 2016 are). I would normally suggest checking ports but as the application is on the same machine it leads me back to documentation

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012, or 2014 - The login must use SQL Server authentication and
have database creation capabilities.
TCP/IP must be enabled before you install Infor
Reporting

Comment: Are you trying to connect Infor LBI to SQL 2014?